# Jackson create new instance when deserialize with custom deserializer instead of just setting the field

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Not easy to explain on a title, but what I try to do is to deserialize a bean and deserialize a specific field on that bean with a custom deserializer.

I have the following json array

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"contact1",
      "phone":"0655555058",
      "image":{  
         "keyname":"bear.jpg",
         "filename":"bear",
         "extension":".jpg"
      }
   },
   {  
      "name":"contact2",
      "phone":"0655555058",
      "image":{  
         "keyname":"bear.jpg",
         "filename":"bear",
         "extension":".jpg"
      }
   }
]
```

and my contact bean

```
public class Contact{

    public String name;
    public String phone;
    public Document image;

}
```

I register a custom deserializer for Document class

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
 module.addDeserializer(Document.class, new DocumentDeserializer());
 mapper.registerModule(module);
```

The deserializer works I have no problems with it. But when I try to deserialize my json array with :

```
List<Contact> list = mapper.readValue(toDeserialize, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Contact.class));
```

Instead of having a list with 2 contacts I have a list with 4 contacts.
2 corrects contacts with the correct name and phone but image null. And 2 other contact with no name and no phone but with image coming from the custom deserializer.

So why the image is not set to the correct contact ?

also I have :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = DocumentDeserializer.class)
```

on my document bean.

I'd like to avoid to add annotation on my image field in my contact class cause I have a lot of Document fields in my application.

What I'm doing wrong ?

UPDATE the deserializer:

```
public class DocumentDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Document> {

    BinariesManager manager = new BasicS3Manager(CommonVars.S3AccessKey, CommonVars.S3SecretKey, CommonVars.S3Bucket);

    public DocumentDeserializer() {
        super(Document.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Document deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String filename = node.get("filename").textValue();
        String extension = node.get("extension").textValue();
        String keyname = node.get("keyname").textValue();

        Document document = buildDocumentBasedOnFileExtension(extension);

        document.setTitle(filename);
        File f = downloadFile(filename, extension, keyname);
        document.load(f);
        return document;
    }
```

Comment: why do you need a custom serializer in the first place? It would help if you supplied the code for DocumentDeserializer

Comment: I receive Json from my api, In my custom deserializer I download my image on S3 depending on the informations I receive on the JSON. The nI build a Document object in my desktop application with the file and some more stuff

Comment: I would not put that kind of logic inside a deserializer. I would process such things after I have parsed the json

Comment: well maybe, but I still want a question to my initial question to know where I'm wrong

Comment: I bet the problem lies in the deserializer so it is hard to tell without seeing the code

Comment: I added the code of the deserializer

Comment: Will it fine to create a custom deserializer which will parse through the JSON string and construct your `Contact` list object?

Answer (score -1):

If everything fails. You could also switch to another approach...

And use json-api library: https://jsonp.java.net/download.html